# return values from dictionary

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

From a cryptocurrency exchange API, I get the following dictionary output:

```py
 {'USDT_ZAP': {'baseVolume': '1726.04494571',
              'high24hr': '0.14152450',
              'highestBid': '0.13294266',
              'id': 390,
              'isFrozen': '0',
              'last': '0.13294267',
              'low24hr': '0.13294265',
              'lowestAsk': '0.13831558',
              'percentChange': '-0.02206798',
              'postOnly': '0',
              'quoteVolume': '12526.72154354'},
 'USDT_ZEC': {'baseVolume': '565577.97474236',
              'high24hr': '320.33154754',
              'highestBid': '293.08695137',
              'id': 180,
              'isFrozen': '0',
              'last': '294.16852418',
              'low24hr': '280.02547427',
              'lowestAsk': '296.44825899',
              'percentChange': '0.02394667',
              'postOnly': '0',
              'quoteVolume': '1893.07747845'},
 'USDT_ZKS': {'baseVolume': '4613.99054173',
              'high24hr': '1.63092636',
              'highestBid': '1.54037192',
              'id': 531,
              'isFrozen': '0',
              'last': '1.54648669',
              'low24hr': '1.51469417',
              'lowestAsk': '1.59193678',
              'percentChange': '-0.00178045',
              'postOnly': '0',
              'quoteVolume': '2876.68162471'},
 'USDT_ZLOT': {'baseVolume': '8.99258242',
               'high24hr': '403.99999999',
               'highestBid': '326.00000000',
               'id': 485,
               'isFrozen': '0',
               'last': '403.00000000',
               'low24hr': '403.00000000',
               'lowestAsk': '403.00000000',
               'percentChange': '-0.00247524',
               'postOnly': '0',
               'quoteVolume': '0.02228339'},
 'USDT_ZRX': {'baseVolume': '91434.83189633',
              'high24hr': '1.76455613',
              'highestBid': '1.65454971',
              'id': 220,
              'isFrozen': '0',
              'last': '1.65105575',
              'low24hr': '1.54644985',
              'lowestAsk': '1.65952795',
              'percentChange': '0.04519587',
              'postOnly': '0',
              'quoteVolume': '55283.27090709'}}
```

I want to create a list of tuples with the first keyword (like `USDT_ZAP`) and the `highestBid` keyword.
The output should look like this:

```py
[("USDT_ZAP", "0.13294266"), ("USDT_ZEC", "293.08695137"), ("USDT_ZKS", "1.54037192"), ("USDT_ZLOT", "326.00000000"), ("USDT_ZRX", "1.65454971")]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Try `[(k, v['highestBid']) for k, v in d.items()]`.

Comment: It works, thank you very much!
But I don't really understand this code. Is there a more extended way to write this code? (in multiple lines)

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try.

```
needed = [(k,data[k]['highestBid']) for count,k in enumerate(data)]
```

output

```
[('USDT_ZAP', '0.13294266'), ('USDT_ZEC', '293.08695137'), ('USDT_ZKS', '1.54037192'), ('USDT_ZLOT', '326.00000000'), ('USDT_ZRX', '1.65454971')]
```